# WordPress WP-Dbmanager 0/1 Query(s) Executed Successfully

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

**WordPress** 3.5.1
**WP-DBManager** 2.63
**Database Type** MYSQL
**Database Version** v5.1.68-cll

Trying to create new table on database for WordPress site using the [WP-DBManager](http://lesterchan.net/portfolio/programming/php/#wordpress-wp-dbmanager) plugin.

I click on the *Run SQL Query* link in the Admin panel and paste in my query which is

```
CREATE TABLE mg_msl_lookup 
  ( 
     device_id    INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     sku          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     manufacturer VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
     phone        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
     esn          BIGINT(18) NOT NULL, 
     msl          INT(6) NOT NULL 
  );
```

I click *Run* and I get the error message

**CREATE TABLE mg_msl_lookup**
**0/1 Query(s) Executed Successfully**

So I did a google search for *"WP-Dbmanager 0/1 Query(s) Executed Successfully"* and found this [forum](http://forums.lesterchan.net/index.php?topic=4328.0) post on the plugin developer's site. It suggested to put the statement all on one line, so I did:

```
CREATE TABLE mg_msl_lookup (Device_Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, SKU varchar(30) NOT NULL, Manufacturer varchar(30) NOT NULL, Phone varchar(50) NOT NULL, ESN bigint(18) NOT NULL, MSL int(6) NOT NULL);
```

Once again I click *Run* and I get the error message:

**CREATE TABLE mg_msl_lookup (Device_Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, SKU varchar(30) NOT NULL, Manufacturer varchar(30) NOT NULL, Phone varchar(50) NOT NULL, ESN bigint(18) NOT NULL, MSL int(6) NOT NULL);**
**0/1 Query(s) Executed Successfully**

I have site wide admin permissions, I can drop/empty tables using the plugin GUI, but for some reason can't create a simple table. I have 40 tables before and after I run the statement.

The plugin developer has these set of instructions on the Run Query page

1. CREATE statement will return an error, which is perfectly normal due to the database class. To confirm that your table has been created check the Manage Database page.
2. UPDATE statement may return an error sometimes due to the newly updated value being the same as the previous value.
3. ALTER statement will return an error because there is no value returned.

I'm gathering that what he means in #1 is that when you run a CREATE statement it will error (so perhaps **0/1 Query(s) Executed Successfully** is normal?) so I followed the directions and go back to the Manage Database page but my new table is not there.

Does anyone have any experience with the WP-DBManager that could assist with this ? This is getting rather frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to use phpMyAdmin to create the tables instead of the plugin, worked like a charm.

Comment: Interesting - for me putting the query on one line was the fix.